# find the rate of change $f(x) = 4\sin^3 x$ when $x = \frac{5\pi}{6}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

find the rate of change $f(x) = 4\sin^3 x$ when $x = \frac{5\pi}{6}$

To find the rate of change I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using the chain rule $h'(x) = g'(f(x)).f'(x)$

$g'(f(x)) = 12\sin^2 x$

$f'(x) = \cos x$

$h'(x) = 12\sin^2 x \cos x$

After this, I am completely stuck, this comes from a paper that does not allow calculators and am I supposed to know what $\frac{5\pi}6$ means and be able to apply it to the derivative function? If so could somebody offer a link or something for me to learn becasue I do not know this.

Comment: It's in radians. $\frac{5\pi}6$ just means $150^\circ$.

Comment: A full circle $360^\circ$ is $2\pi$ in radians, just scale them.

Comment: You need to know Trigonometry. Many sources exist, for example:http://sites.csn.edu/istewart/mathweb/math127/any_angles/any_angle.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trig by Reference Triangles**:

The angle $\frac{5 \pi}{6}$ in radians will be given by $150^o$. This simple conversion can be done by remembering that $180^o = \pi$  $rad $.

To solve for

$h'(x)=12 sin^2x cosx$
$h'( \frac{ 5 \pi}{6} )=12 sin^2 ( \frac{5 \pi}{6}) cos( \frac{5 \pi}{6} )$

we can use right-angled triangles of the standard angles. E.g. here  our reference triangle is the $(90, 60, 30^o)$ triangle in the secondant quadrant of the cartesian plane. However, we are more interested in the radian form of the triangle ($ \frac{\pi}{2},  \frac{ \pi}{3},  \frac{\pi}{6}) $.  The respective side lengths of this triangle are therefore  $(2, - \sqrt{3}, 1)$.

$sin (\frac{5 \pi}{6} ) = \frac{ - \sqrt {3}}{2}$

and,

$-cos (\frac{5 \pi}{6} ) = \frac{1}{2}$

(See link:[Reference Triangles](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ATT3/referenceTriangles.htm))

Comment: In the second quadrant, sine is positive and cosine is negative.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Indeed it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The rate of change at $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ is simply $h'(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = 12 \sin^2(\frac{5\pi}{6})\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6})$.

Your confusion probably arises from the fact that you are used to dealing with degrees instead of radians.

The period of $\sin, \cos$ is $2\pi$ or $360$ degrees. One radian is $\frac{360}{2\pi}$ degrees. Spend some time studying the unit circle,
[image: unit circle]

and you'll get used to radians in no time.

In the parentheses you can also see the $\cos$ and $\sin$ values of the angles. Check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) for more!